# Из-за explode не отображаются данные

Tags: php, sql

не отображаются данные из-за explode.
Я ее использую чтобы разделить запись в таблице "PLAN-1" так как из-за тире sql выдает ошибку.

```
    <?php
connect();
    $order_sql = $M->query("SELECT * FROM orders WHERE use_id='".$user['id']."' AND type='SERTIFICATE'");
    close();
    $plan = $order_sql->fetch_array();
    $pl = explode("-", $plan['names']);
    connect();
    $data_sql = $M->query("SELECT * FROM usr_ssl WHERE ssl_user_id='".$plan['use_id']."'");
    close();
?>
```

Comment: Зачем вы при каждом запросе открываете и закрываете соединение с БД?

Comment: Я думаю так безопаснее

Comment: В чем безопасность - неясно.

Comment: Знаю, отправите на изучение, но если не сложно покажите как бы вы исправили такой код

Comment: @ShahinHasanov вы думаете так безопаснее. Я могу сказать, что у вас здесь лишняя нагрузка на приложение и никакой дополнительной безопасности здесь не несёт. А зачем вам переменная $pl, если она в коде нигде не используется? Мне совершенно неясно что вы хотите здесь сделать. Вы сначала получаете запись из таблицы orders, где use_id=$user['id'], затем поле name у первой запись в результате (может и единственную) разделяете на массив через тире, затем вы ищите данные в usr_ssl по ssl_user_id=$plan['use_id']. А переменная $pl так и остаётся неиспользуемой переменной

Answer (score 0):

У вас много плохих действий:

1. Открывать соединение с бд стоит только в самом начале работы всего приложения, закрывать под самый конец. Открывать/закрывать постоянно **нельзя** у вас во-первых бесполезная нагрузка, во-вторых у вас может нарушиться консистентность данных
2. Ваша генерация запросов имеет уязвимость SQL-инъекций, поэтому думайте над экранированием и валидацией, а не подставляйте налету значения
3. Используйте итератор для разбора записей после выполнения запроса

```
    while ($row = $order_sql->fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo $row["userid"];
        echo $row["fullname"];
        echo $row["userstatus"];
    }
```

Хотя бы так. В лучшем случае посмотрите в сторону ORM, для более явного управления сущностями